# Big-Oh notation for if else loops

Tags: big-o

Given the script below, I need help figuring out the Big-Oh notation.

```
p = 0

if a < b :

   for i in range(1,n) :

    j = 1

    while j < i :

        p = p + j

        j = 2 * j

else :

    for i in range(1, n) :

      p = p + 1

    for j in range(1,n) :

      p = p + j

    for k in range(1,n) :

      p = p + k
```

This is mainly because I'm unsure about the Big-Oh notation for if and else statements. I'm thinking the answer could just be n because the for loops are in the range of n, but I'm unsure about how the nested while loop would affect the answer or if the if else statement changes it.

Comment: I noticed some of your questions and that you have not accepted any answer. You can accept an answer that you think is helpful. This gives you some reputation so you can do more things on this site. You should also take a minute to have a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Since with Big-oh notation, you are considering the upper bounds, it should be O(n * lg n) here in the worst case and O(n) in the best case.

Edit : I didn't notice the `j = j * 2`, @AbcAeffchen has incorporated that already.

Regarding best case and worst case, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case).

Comment: What does the worst case and best case actually mean? I've only learnt that the Big-Oh notation is one answer? Sorry if this is really obvious, maybe I haven't learnt it yet? haha

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input `a` and `b`:

Best case (`a ≥ b`):
Three loops running from `1` to `n`. So this is in `O(n)`.

Worst case (`a < b`):
One for loop running from `1` to `n`, with a nested while loop.
The while loop has the breaking condition `j < i`. In the while loop, `j` is always multiplied by `2`, so `j` contains a power of `2`. The question is how big has to be `x` such that `2x < i` holds, and the answer is `log₂ i ≤ log₂ n`. So you get a worst case of `O(n⋅log n)`.

The code you posted is simple enough to find a best and a worst case. If the algorithm is much more complex, you only look for the worst case complexity.